# An intuitive approach to a Lemma related to subgroups of quotient groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition, group-homomorphism, proof-without-words

Consider the following Lemma:

> Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $T$ be a subgroup of $G/K$,then there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $T=H/K$. (Of course, it is automatically implied that $H$ must contain $K$ or else $H/K$ makes no sense.)
>
> (Actually it says that any subgroup of quotient group by $K$,has the form $H/K$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.)

I am trying to proceed intuitively to get hold of the formal proof.

Quotienting by a normal subgroup essentially means consider the cosets induced by the subgroup and collapse each to a point. Now $T$ is a subgroup of $G/K$, so basically it is a collection of points from $G/K$ which are actually some cosets of $K$ in $G$ (reduced to a point).

So, let us expand the coset-points to the original parent points. I mean to say, we have collapsed cosets via the epimorphism $f(x)=xK ,x\in G$, so let us now expand the coset points, *i.e.*, go reverse.

Consider $f^{-1}\{yK $ cosets of $G\mid yK \in T\}$, *i.e.*, $f^{-1}(T)$, which is basically the union of all the cosets present in the set $T$. Now clearly this set contains $K$ as $K$ is in $T$ because $K=eK$ is the identity of $G/K$ and $T$ is a subgroup of $G/K$. One can easily verify this to be a subgroup of $G$ by the properties of homomorhism and since we have expanded coset points to get the set $f^{-1}(T)$, so collapsing it again will give the same coset point collection, *i.e.*, $T$, so of course $T=H/K$.

> Is my intuition correct?

Comment: Yup! Looks good to me

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks,Btw Do you have some picture in your mind that you can post as an answer,it would be very nice to understand it diagramatically or visually,also you can add some more information if you want.

Comment: Sorry for the wait - yeah I can answer and try to add some intuition. I think the picture you have in mind is a good one. Give me a second to make some diagrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct -- if $H \leq G/K$, then we can write $H = \widetilde{H}/K$ where $\widetilde{H} \leq G$.

The idea is to set $\widetilde{H} = f^{-1}(H)$. It is routine to verify that this is a subgroup of $G$, and that $f(\widetilde{H}) = f(f^{-1}(H)) = H$.

Here is the requested picture for how I visualize what is happening. It is similar in spirit to the description you gave:

[image: projection picture]

The bubbles over a point $x \in G/K$ are exactly the $g \in G$ such that $f(g) = x$. You'll notice these are all isomorphic, as they are exactly the cosets of $K$. Thus each bubble looks like a copy of $K$. Then a subgroup $H \leq G/K$, shown as the circled region, lifts to a subgroup in $G$ which looks like $H$ copies of $K$. This is the set of bubbles offset from the others. If we ignore the bubbles and just look at the 24 points in $G$ which lie above $H$, this is exactly $\widetilde{H}$, and this picture makes it clear that projecting these down to $G/K$ gives exactly $H$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^